# React | Why the defaultValue of the input isn't being updated?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a stateful component that calls a CEP promise, to fetch data from post offices. This data is fetched when the Zip input is fulfilled with 9 chars - 8 number and an '-' - and return an object with desired information.

Heres the function:

```
  const handleZipCode = useCallback(
    async ({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const { value } = target;

      try {
        if (value.length === 9 && isDigit(value[8])) {
          const zip = await cep(value);

          if (zip?.city) {
            setZipData(zip);
          } else
            addressFormRef.current?.setErrors({
              user_zip_code: 'CEP not found',
            });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        addressFormRef.current?.setErrors({
          user_zip_code: e.message ?? 'CEP not found',
        });
      }
    },
    [isDigit]
  );
```

Then, on the return I have some fields, example:

```
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Address</legend>
              <Input
                mask=''
                name='user_address'
                placeholder='Rua um dois três'
                defaultValue={zipData.street}
              />
            </fieldset>
```

Here's the Input component:

```
const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ name, ...rest }) => {
  const { fieldName, defaultValue, registerField, error } = useField(name);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: inputRef.current,
      path: 'value',
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      setValue(ref: any, value: string) {
        ref.setInputValue(value);
      },
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      clearValue(ref: any) {
        ref.setInputValue('');
      },
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <ReactInputMask ref={inputRef} defaultValue={defaultValue} {...rest} />
      {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

However the zipData seems to update, but the default value is not fulfilled. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is this Input component? did you make it, or is it from a library?

Comment: Is from a library. Actually I'm using unform and react-input-mask. I editted to add the Input component.

Answer (score 2):

The default value will not change, as `unform` is an uncontrolled form library, the defaultValue will be set on the first render of the page and then will not change anymore.

To fix your problem you can do something like:

```js
// on your handleZipCode function
formRef.current.setData({
   zipData: {
     street: zipResult.street,
   },
});
```

Comment: I got this error: `ref.setInputValue is not a function`.

Comment: Didn't you forget the `current`?

Comment: A known issue maybe: https://github.com/Rocketseat/unform/issues/242#issuecomment-706175761

Comment: Yeah, tbh im not a big fan of unform at all, i recommend you `reac-hooks-form`

Comment: Okay, next project I'll use, on this will create a giant extra work to change. I'll search for another way to change the value! Thank you!